# How to use a database across two availability zones

Tags: mysql, replication

I have servers in the USA and Japan for my website. At the moment they are both connecting to a MySQL server in the USA, which is obviously perfect for my local USA clients but quite slow for my Japanese clients.

What is the best strategy for reducing latency? How can I introduce a local MySQL server for the Japanese end and sync these up?

I have considered master-master replication but this appears to be an incomplete and unstable solution. Are there any other suggestions?